# How to iterate child in golang with parent id?

Tags: go

I want to iterate children that have parent id and put on children properti in json?
I have try to do that, but children just show in 1 level on children, and not working on 2 level, how to do that?

```
type ResponseMenu struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" form:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Title       string             `json:"title" form:"title" bson:"title"`
    Children    []ResponseMenu     `json:"children" form:"children" bson:"children"`
    ParentId    string             `json:"parent_id" form:"parent_id" bson:"parent_id"`
}


func iterateChild(resChild []model.ResponseMenu, obj *model.ResponseMenu) {
    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
    // fmt.Println("len child: ", len(resChild))

    obj.Children = make([]model.ResponseMenu, len(resChild))
    if len(resChild) > 0 {
        jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(resChild)
        fmt.Println("resChild: ", string(jsonData))
        obj.Children = append([]model.ResponseMenu{}, resChild...)
        for _, sv := range resChild {
            var resSc []model.ResponseMenu
            fc := bson.M{"parent_id": sv.ID.Hex()}
            cursor, err := menuCollection.Find(ctx, fc)
            defer cancel()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("halo")
            }
            if err = cursor.All(ctx, &resSc); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("loha")
            }
            iterateChild(resSc, &sv)
        }
    }
}

func GetListMenu(c *gin.Context) {
    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
    var response []*model.ResponseMenu
    var resChild []model.ResponseMenu
    q := c.Query("q")
    perPage, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Query("per_page"))
    if err != nil || perPage == 0 {
        perPage = 10
    }
    page, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Query("page"))
    if page > 0 { // page start from index 0
        page -= 1
    }
    filter := bson.M{
        "title": primitive.Regex{
            Pattern: q,
            Options: "i", // i for case sensitive uppercase or lowercase
        },
        "is_parent": true,
        "parent_id": "",
    }
    options := options.Find()
    options.SetSkip(int64(page * perPage))
    options.SetLimit(int64(perPage))
    options.SetSort(bson.D{{"created_at", -1}})
    cursor, err := menuCollection.Find(ctx, filter, options)
    defer cancel()
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "status":  false,
            "message": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "error":   err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &response); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "status":  false,
            "message": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    for _, v := range response {
        // fmt.Println(v.ID.Hex())
        filterChild := bson.M{"parent_id": v.ID.Hex()}
        cursor, err := menuCollection.Find(ctx, filterChild)
        defer cancel()
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "status":  false,
                "message": http.StatusInternalServerError,
                "error":   err.Error(),
            })
            return
        }
        if err = cursor.All(ctx, &resChild); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "status":  false,
                "message": err.Error(),
            })
            return
        }
        iterateChild(resChild, v)
    }
    if len(response) > 0 {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status":  true,
            "message": "Success retrieve data",
            "data":    response,
        })
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "status":  false,
            "message": "Data not found",
            "data":    response,
        })
    }
}
```

this is the database that I have
[image]

and this is the response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "63a63cc231bc5e0d42efe54f",
            "title": "Dashboard",
            "translate": "",
            "type": "group",
            "children": [
                {
                    "_id": "63a63d0c31bc5e0d42efe551",
                    "title": "Settings",
                    "translate": "",
                    "type": "item",
                    "children": null,
                    "parent_id": "63a63cc231bc5e0d42efe54f",
                    "level": 1,
                    "icon": "home",
                    "url": "admin/setting",
                    "permissions": [
                        "view",
                        "add",
                        "edit",
                        "delete"
                    ],
                    "created_at": "2022-12-23T23:43:08Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-12-23T23:43:08Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "63a63d3c31bc5e0d42efe552",
                    "title": "Roles",
                    "translate": "",
                    "type": "item",
                    "children": null,
                    "parent_id": "63a63cc231bc5e0d42efe54f",
                    "level": 1,
                    "icon": "home",
                    "url": "admin/setting",
                    "permissions": [
                        "view",
                        "add",
                        "edit",
                        "delete"
                    ],
                    "created_at": "2022-12-23T23:43:56Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-12-23T23:43:56Z"
                }
            ],
            "parent_id": "",
            "level": 0,
            "icon": "home",
            "url": "admin/dashboard",
            "permissions": null,
            "created_at": "2022-12-23T23:41:54Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-23T23:41:54Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success retrieve data",
    "status": true
}
```

children with title Setting should have children with Title Origo, but not show children.
How to show children in nested children?

Comment: Please try to provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Unfortunately your current code has a number of issues and is difficult to follow - [this example in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BKKiWbPAh24) will hopefully point you in the right direction (or help you to provide a simpler example).

Comment: @Brits Thanks, its worked, you save my day! I update to `iterateChild(resSc, &obj.Children[i])`